# kernel panic - not syncing; error loading shared libraries: lib.so.6; unable to find persistent home medium

Tags: boot, kernel, persistence

I have been trying to find posts with the same issue as mine, but I had no luck yet, hence I'm posting.

I have Ubuntu 20.04 (ubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso) installed on 64GB USB drive with help of a Rufus persistent live USB. I've been using it for a long time.

Yesterday the screen turned blank. I plugged in the power, but it didn't help and then it shut down. All attempts to reboot lead me to the following screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

Grub screen doesn't have any recovery / advance options as recommended in other posts. I am able to plug this drive in an Ubuntu 18.04 live USB and see the folder structure as shown in the Ubuntu and writable screenshots.

[image: ububtu]

[image: writable]

I don't know if it's a kernel issue or if some other file is corrupt/stuck which is preventing it from booting up.

UPDATE : Followed steps recommended by mcendu. Made some progress. libc.so.6 error is not showing up anymore. Here's the latest screenshot after replacing libc.so.6 of persistent 21.04 from the live USB 21.04.
[image: screenshot_2]

Answer (score -1):

A core operating system library (here libc) is corrupted, so you are forced to fix the issue from outside.

You should start by making a new Ubuntu 20.04 live drive/disc from another working OS, boot into it, then fsck you installation's root partition.

```
# umount /dev/sdb2
# fsck /dev/sdb2
# mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt
```

Check libc.so.6 after fsck, because fsck might have deleted it. You can either use `file`, or you can just run it from the command line. If you get something like the following, libc is fixed and you can do the reboot test right away:

```
$ file /mnt/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
/mnt/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.31.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object,
  x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter
  /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=..., for GNU/Linux 3.2.0,
  stripped
```

If the following appears, then you are out of luck:

```
$ file /mnt/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
/mnt/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: cannot open
  `/mnt/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6' (No such file or directory)
```

In this case, copy the libc from your installation media to your Ubuntu installation as a temporary measure, then reinstall libc through APT after the installation successfully boots.

```
# install -m 755 -o root -g root -T /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 \
    /mnt/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
# reboot
```

Side note: most thumb drives use worse NAND chips than SSDs. Beware of data corruption.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 

Just to clarify, should I ‘ fsck’ the ‘writable’ partition? If yes, the path under which I see lib after mounting is : /mnt/usr/lib/x86…. 

If this is correct.. I tried this, no error on ‘file’ but still not able to boot

Comment: Yes, you should fsck that partition. Further boot logs would be helpful after fixing libc.

Comment: Was able to run fsck on ‘writable’. Saw some fixes, missed out on taking note. Ran again and things came out fine this time. 
But as I said, file on libc worked fine. 
Sadly not able to boot, getting kernel panic. 

Just fyi, I did it on Ubuntu 18. Thought of trying there first and if copy of libc is needed,  will go for 20

Comment: Check the logs just before and on the panic line. If anything is different, please add it to an edit of the question. If it stays identical, you should replace libc.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Looks like few more files are corrupt and need replacement.

Comment: mcendu- any suggestions on what to go for next ?